# When running a Python Program, the error "'return' outside function" pops up

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

**When running a Python Program, the error "'return' outside function" pops up.**

I am trying to make a list of floating-point numbers and returns a list with each element having a 10 per cent discount.

```
def discount_ten():
nondis=float[1.10,2.40,5.20,6.30,6.70]
for i in nondis:
  |return(nondis/10) #<- "|" is the red highlighting.#
print(nondis)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: This doesn't look like Python code at all.

Comment: @TFX, see if the answer posted helps?

Comment: @DirtyBit Thanks a lot, it worked. c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad Indentation, you need to properly indent your function definition, i.e:

```
def discount_ten():
    nondis=float[1.10,2.40,5.20,6.30,6.70]
    for i in nondis:
      return(nondis/10) 
    print(nondis)
```

> Note: Python follows a particular style of indentation to define the
>   code, **since Python functions don't have any explicit begin or end like
>   curly braces to indicate the start and stop for the function**, they
>   have to rely on this indentation.

**EDIT** (fixed for your desired output):

Using a list to store the results, you do not need a `return` in the loop, since that would exit the loop and print only `0.11000000000000001` for the very first iteration. Furthermore, Use a `round()` to round of to nearest desired decimal places:

```
def discount_ten():
    nondis = [1.10,2.40,5.20,6.30,6.70]
    res = []                      # empty list to store the results
    for i in nondis:
      res.append(round(i/10, 2))  # appending each (rounded off to 2) result to the list
    return res                    # returning the list

print(discount_ten())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[0.11, 0.24, 0.52, 0.63, 0.67]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your function is not properly indented, look at following code:

**This function print the desire output:**

```
def discount_ten():
   nondis=[1.10,2.40,5.20,6.30,6.70]
   for i in nondis:
     print(i/10)
```

**This function return list of desired output:**

```
def discount_ten():
    nondis=float[1.10,2.40,5.20,6.30,6.70]
    disc_ten=[]
    for i in nondis:
       disc.append(i/10)
    return disc
```

> **Note:** A code block (body of a function, loop etc.) starts with indentation and ends with the first unindented line. The amount of indentation is up to you, but it must be consistent throughout that block.

--

Comment: Thanks a lot, the program runs, but it prints 'None'

Comment: please share your desire output

Comment: 0.11,0.24,0.52,0.63,0.67

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

in Python, indentation is an important part of the code. each block adds one level of indentation. to define a function, you must indent each line of the function by the same amount.

```
def discount_ten():
    distcount_list = []
    nondis = [1.10,2.40,5.20,6.30,6.70]
    for i in nondis:
        distcount_list.append(round(i/10,2))
    return distcount_list
print(discount_ten())
```